# How to set Api response message like {Success or Not - message} in UI / Screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api

I want to display message on screen or a snackbar or AlertDialog which get from api response.

So how to get API response message?

Here is my Function for Validate OTP as below in api_manager.dart file.

Now how can i pass the snackbar to my screen?

```
Future validateOtp(BuildContext context, String otp, LogedinUser? userData,
      UserPlan? userPlan) async {
    final String otpUrl = "$baseUrl/otp/validate";
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'user_id': userData!.userId,
      'otp': otp,
      'device_id': userData.deviceId,
    });
    var response = await dio.post(otpUrl, data: formData);

    final validateOtpData = validateOtpFromJson(response.data);
    final status = validateOtpData.success;

    print(response.data);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var res = response.data;
      print(userData.userId);
      print(userData.deviceId);
      print(otp);
      print(res);
      if (status == 1) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DashBoard(
              user: userData,
              userPlan: userPlan,
            ),
          ),
        );
        return status;
      } else if (status == 0) {
        final apiMsg = validateOtpData.msg;
        final snackBar =
            SnackBar(content: Text(apiMsg!), backgroundColor: Colors.grey);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my OTP verifivation screen.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ApiManager().validateOtp(context, otp, userData, userPlan).then((apiMsg) {
      setState(() {
        //msg = apiMsg;
      });
    });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        OtpTextField(
          numberOfFields: 6,
          fieldWidth: 43,
          focusedBorderColor: Colors.black,
          onSubmit: (String otpValue) {
            setState(() {
              otp = otpValue;
            });
          },
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ApiManager().validateOtp(context, otp, userData, userPlan);
          },
          child: Text("Verify"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here is the response for invalid or expired OTP .

[image]

And this is valid OTP response.

[image]

Below is Validate OTP Model Class in validate_otp.dart file.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final validateOtp = validateOtpFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ValidateOtp validateOtpFromJson(String str) =>
    ValidateOtp.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String validateOtpToJson(ValidateOtp data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ValidateOtp {
  ValidateOtp({
    required this.success,
    required this.msg,
  });

  int success;
  String? msg;

  factory ValidateOtp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ValidateOtp(
        success: json["success"] == null ? null : json["success"],
        msg: json["msg"] == null ? null : json["msg"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        "success": success == null ? null : success,
        "msg": msg == null ? null : msg,
      };
}
```

So when OTP is incorrect or expired i want to display **OTP is either expired or not valid.** response from api on Validate OTP Screen.

Thank you.

Comment: I corrected my answer below. Check if it answeres your query.

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet should help. It gives you a very basic idea of how to achieve your purpose.

N.B: Example is just an abstract explanation

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: OTP(),));
}

class OTP extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OTPState createState() => _OTPState();
}

class _OTPState extends State<OTP> {
  String error = "";

  Future OtpValidation() async{
    error= "Error occured";
  }

  Future validateOtp() async {
   await OtpValidation(); //Do your Networking & logic
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: !error.isEmpty
          ? Text(error)
          : Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {validateOtp();},
            child: Text("Validate OTP"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model `ValidateOtp` exposes the data member `msg` which you can use to access the "msg" field from the received JSON.

Just do

```
var response = await dio.post(otpUrl, data: formData);
final validateOtpData = validateOtpFromJson(response.data);
final apiMsg = validateOtpData.msg;
final status = validateOtpData.success;

print(apiMsg!);
```

Just remember that `validateOtpData.msg` would be null in case of successful verification so you'd have to handle that case appropriately.

Now to show a snackbar on success or failure, you could do something like this

```
if(response.statusCode != 200){
    final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(apiMsg!), backgroundColor: Colors.red);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackbar);
}
```

For the `context` variable, you'd have to pass an additional `BuildContext` from the widget from which you are trying to show the snackbar. So change your function arguments to look something like

```
validateOtp(
      context, String otp, LogedinUser? userData, UserPlan? userPlan, BuildContext context)
```

And now pass the `context` as well when you try to call the function.

Comment: yes I did it, and i get response in console.  but how i can show this msg on otp validation screen. when OTP is invalid or expired i want to show this msg on screen.

Comment: I've updated the answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Here i need some help, i will updated the function in question please check it out.

Comment: BuildContext context now allow because it says context is already difined

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where is this error coming from?

Comment: there is no error but if i type wrong otp then Functions else if (status == 0) part is executed. So in this else if i created a snackbar so how i can access snackbar in my screen?

Comment: if you want to see i can put the otp screen part in question

Comment: both function and screen were i call th function

Comment: What's the problem that you are facing right now? What do you mean by "access the snackbar"? Is the snackbar not showing up on the UI for status=0 case?

Comment: my otp verification is works perfectly and redirect to dashboard but when i pass wrong otp i want to display snackbar , okay i put the otp screen part in question i just want to display response msg in snack bar on otp screen

Comment: Yes i already shared the solution for your question, is the snack bar not visible when you enter incorrect otp? Is there any error? I won't be able to help you if anymore if you are not able to elaborate.

Comment: yes i can not able to display snackbar on wrong otp